deserialize program data in log notification
I am trying to decode program data in a log notification with the following code:
import { deserialize } from "borsh";
const LOG_PROGRAMDATA_SCHEMA = {
    struct: { name: "string" ,symbol: "string", uri: "string" }  //from solnafm
  };

const program_data = 'G3KpTd7rY3YNAAAAQlVORExFRCBQRU5HVQYAAABCVU5ETEVDAAAAaHR0cHM6Ly9pcGZzLmlvL2lwZnMvUW1ZdzY1WkxQMUhUdXFOdzNrQllpdXhkRGNQOW5xWTJlSmpZdGpTd1lZS05ZQwQRBm8MluSSPn07JLVylyl9fEhruZBBGubiqpRNzNif9xQ6WBKoNWbAilWVgC2UlsFyeY5hOr4G4Yj5QaW+bQZtjdsv57C0K2nWYY2eQ5dY4P5I0CDudhEcxFNJN62RZw=='

const buffer = Buffer.from(program_data, "base64");
const len = buffer.length;
// console.log("Buffer:", buffer.toString());
try {
  const decoded = deserialize(LOG_PROGRAMDATA_SCHEMA, buffer, false);
  console.log("Decoded:", decoded);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Error:", e);
}

but got this error:
Error: Error: Error in schema, the buffer is smaller than expected
    at DecodeBuffer.assert_enough_buffer (file:///mnt/4T/yolo/data/helius/node_modules/.pnpm/borsh@2.0.0/node_modules/borsh/lib/esm/buffer.js:46:19)
    at DecodeBuffer.consume_bytes (file:///mnt/4T/yolo/data/helius/node_modules/.pnpm/borsh@2.0.0/node_modules/borsh/lib/esm/buffer.js:59:14)
    at BorshDeserializer.decode_string (file:///mnt/4T/yolo/data/helius/node_modules/.pnpm/borsh@2.0.0/node_modules/borsh/lib/esm/deserialize.js:54:49)
    at BorshDeserializer.decode_value (file:///mnt/4T/yolo/data/helius/node_modules/.pnpm/borsh@2.0.0/node_modules/borsh/lib/esm/deserialize.js:15:29)
    at BorshDeserializer.decode_struct (file:///mnt/4T/yolo/data/helius/node_modules/.pnpm/borsh@2.0.0/node_modules/borsh/lib/esm/deserialize.js:129:32)
    at BorshDeserializer.decode_value (file:///mnt/4T/yolo/data/helius/node_modules/.pnpm/borsh@2.0.0/node_modules/borsh/lib/esm/deserialize.js:31:29)
    at BorshDeserializer.decode (file:///mnt/4T/yolo/data/helius/node_modules/.pnpm/borsh@2.0.0/node_modules/borsh/lib/esm/deserialize.js:8:21)
    at deserialize (file:///mnt/4T/yolo/data/helius/node_modules/.pnpm/borsh@2.0.0/node_modules/borsh/lib/esm/index.js:16:25)
    at <anonymous> (/mnt/4T/yolo/data/helius/testDeserialize.ts:12:19)

I can the original buffer is string is large enough, and print out the buffer, I can see the name and symbols and uri. Why did I get this error?

The error you're encountering with the borsh library in your deserialization code is due to an improperly defined schema. The LOG_PROGRAMDATA_SCHEMA does not match the expected structure needed for deserialization with Borsh.
Here's what you need to fix:

Define a proper schema: Ensure that the schema correctly defines the structure of your serialized data.
Deserialization function: Utilize the correct functionality of Borsh's deserialize method.

Updated Code Example
First, correct the schema definition. It should follow the structure expected by Borsh.
import { deserialize, Schema, BinaryReader, BinaryWriter } from 'borsh';  
import base58 from 'bs58';  

class LogProgramData {  
    constructor(properties) {  
        Object.keys(properties).forEach((key) => {  
            this[key] = properties[key];  
        });  
    }  
}  

const schema = new Map([  
    [LogProgramData, {  
        kind: 'struct',  
        fields: [  
            ['name', 'string'],  
            ['symbol', 'string'],  
            ['uri', 'string'],  
        ]  
    }]  
]);  

const program_data_base64 = 'G3KpTd7rY3YNAAAAQlVORExFRCBQRU5HVQYAAABCVU5ETEVDAAAAaHR0cHM6Ly9pcGZzLmlvL2lwZnMvUW1ZdzY1WkxQMUhUdXFOdzNrQllpdXhkRGNQOW5xWTJlSmpZdGpTd1lZS05ZQwQRBm8MluSSPn07JLVylyl9fEhruZBBGubiqpRNzNif9xQ6WBKoNWbAilWVgC2UlsFyeY5hOr4G4Yj5QaW+bQZtjdsv57C0K2nWYY2eQ5dY4P5I0CDudhEcxFNJN62RZw==';  
const buffer = Buffer.from(program_data_base64, 'base64');  

try {  
    const decoded = deserialize(schema, LogProgramData, buffer);  
    console.log('Decoded:', decoded);  
} catch (e) {  
    console.error('Error:', e);  
}  

Explanation:

Define the Class: Create a class LogProgramData that matches the structure of your data.
Create Schema: Use borsh to create a schema describing the structure of your data.
Deserialize: Pass the schema, the class, and the buffer into the deserialize method.

This should resolve the Error in schema, the buffer is smaller than expected issue and let you successfully deserialize the program data.

The solution is based on the earlier borsh version, I downgraded to 0.7 and use the solution, but still got "Expected buffer length ... isn't within bounds".  Since borsh is supposed to have the length stored in the first 4 bytes, I use buffer.readUInt32LE(0) , readUint16LE(0) to get the length, all got really big numbers, tried BE version as well. I think I am missing something in the Solana string serialization, maybe it is just stored characters with null terminated, but don't see this in anywhere Solana document.
